# how to solve tensorflow mnist load problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Linux Ubuntu 20.04
pyenv 3.7
tensorflow 2.4.0

I'm import mnist.load_data()

Do you know how to solve??

Try import ssl and !curl -OL but
I can't solve it

Please!! solve it nnn

```
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1316                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1317                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1318             except OSError as err: # timeout error

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1228         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1229         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1230 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1274             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1275         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1276 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1223             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1224         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1225 

~/.pyenv/versions/tensor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, file_hash, cache_subdir, hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)
    280       except URLError as e:
    281         raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
--> 282     except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt) as e:
    283       if os.path.exists(fpath):
    284         os.remove(fpath)

Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz: None -- [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1045)
```

Comment: You can execute this code `import tensorflow as tf; mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist; (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()`.

Comment: yes!! but it's not working

Comment: It looks strange. May i know the error, which you have received after executing above code?